# AnyLogic: Whether requirements and constraints in optimization experiments can be set to be compared with variables

Tags: optimization, anylogic

I am trying to do some optimisation experiments, and currently I find that the constraints and requirement can only allows me to compare the parameters with constant.

As the value may always change in my model, is that possible to repalce the constant with variable?
[Image: Now I can only set it as 0.45 which is constant, but actually it may change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FV8h1.png)

I tried but AnyLogic don't allow me to enter variable name in that cell.

Answer (score 1):

You have something wrong in your design then since. The point of parameters when used in an optimization experiments, is for them to remain constant. If they will change during the simulation, how can you really do this?

What you can do instead, is making the parameter be the initial value of a variable... in which case you will use that value as the initial value of the parameter and you will use the parameter holding that initial value in the optimization experiment.

Finally, one of the main differences between parameters and variables, is that parameters can be used in experiments, while variables cannot.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply, Felipe. Actually, the input of my model is changing, like in daily intervals and will last for years, so if I want to get the parameter set for each day which is optimised according to that day's input, may I ask how to achieve this?

Comment: this sounds like a sequential decision making process, when you need to optimize sequences, you have to use Reinforcement Learning, and not the optimization experiment... it's much more difficult

Comment: Now I can optimise for 1 day's input, which is fixed, I will get the optimal parameter set for that day. I will record this set, and then it moves to the next day, do the same process, but will have another parameter set, which will also be recorded. So finally I want to have a table, which contains the input per day, and the parameter set of each day. Does it have to use RL?

Comment: I don't think doing that makes sense in a world in which things are stochastic... if you optimize every day, then you run the simulation and since it's stochastic the first day is different and now you have invalid optimized parameters for future days... for sequences, you can't really use an optimization approach in my opinion, so yes, RL... but you can ask others for more opinions on this

Comment: Currently the input of mine is not stochastic, but it will changing based on a function. so if not stochastic, is it possible to generate the table contains each day's data? Thanks a lot for your reply